# Different way of data binding

Tags: angularjs, json, forms

I have a json file with 200 questions and answers. User should go through it and translate them. Structure of json file looks like this:

```
categoryName": "Name of Category",
"questions": [
{
  "questionName": "date",
  "questionField": "dateOfInspection",
  "questionRequired": "1",
  "questionType": "datefield",
  "questionLabel": "Date",
  "answers": [
    {
      "answerName": "date",
      "answerType": "datefield"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "questionName": "dealer",
  "questionField": "dealer",
  "questionRequired": "1",
  "questionType": "textfield",
  "questionLabel": "Dealer",
  "answers": [
    {
      "answerName": "dealer",
      "answerType": "textfield",
      "answerDescription": "Description Text"
    }
  ]
}
```

I display all questions as a form on page:

```
<form name="questionnaireSubmit" action=""  id="q" ng-click="submit()" novalidate>
            <div ng-repeat="categoryNQuestions in questionnaireFull">
                <p id="categoryName" >
                    {{categoryNQuestions.categoryName}}
                </p>

                <div ng-repeat="question in categoryNQuestions.questions" id="questionAnswer">
                    <label id="question">
                        {{question.questionField}}
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.qs.questionField" name="{{question.questionField}}" placeholder ="{{question.questionField}}" />

                    <div ng-show="question.questionDescription">
                        <label id="description">
                            {{question.questionDescription}}
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{question.questionDescription}}" />
                    </div>



            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit_btn" class="center-block" >
        </form>
```

When user press submit button I want to generate new json object with translated questions and answers. 
But two way data binding doesn't work here, because I have around 200 questionField fields and `ng-model` doesn't accept {{questionField}}.

How can I bind data in other way?

My controller:

```
var app = angular.module('questionnaire', []);
app.controller('myQuestionCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http, $window) {

    var that=this;
    //$scope.question; 


$http.get("json_file_url")
    .then(function(response) {

    $scope.questionnaireFull = {};

    $scope.questionnaireFull = response.data.categories;



    //create new questionnaire with cleared q_labels, q_descriptions, a_labels and a_descriptions



    $scope.questionnaireEmptyDuplicate = angular.copy(response.data);



    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.questionnaireEmptyDuplicate.categories.length; i++){
        var caregories = $scope.questionnaireEmptyDuplicate.categories[i];

        for (var j = 0; j< caregories.questions.length; j++){
            var questions = caregories.questions[j];


            if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull(questions.questionLabel) === false) {
                questions.questionLabel = angular.clearValue(questions.questionLabel);
            }

            if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull(questions.questionDescription) === false) {
                questions.questionDescription = angular.clearValue(questions.questionDescription);
            }

            angular.forEach(questions.answers, function(answer_value, answer_key) {

                if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull(questions.questionDescription) === false) {
                    answer_value.answerLabel = angular.clearValue(answer_value.answerLabel);
                }

                if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull(questions.questionDescription) === false) {
                    answer_value.answerDescription = angular.clearValue(answer_value.answerDescription);
                }

            })


        }

    }

    console.log($scope.questionnaireEmptyDuplicate);



});  /*end of $http.get*/




$scope.submit = function () { 
    alert("function is working"); //Add this line to your code to confirm your function is called.
    $window.location.href = "https://www.google.de/";

} 


//functions
angular.isUndefinedOrNull  = function(val) {
    return angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null 
}

angular.clearValue = function(val){
    val = '';
    return val;
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I made a snippet for you with a simplified solution (I'm not taking in consideration the different caregories) where I'm translating just the name of the question, but you can easily scale this solution to translate whatever you want.

```js
var json = {
 "categoryName": "Name of Category",
 "questions": [
  {
   "questionName": "date",
   "questionField": "dateOfInspection",
   "questionRequired": "1",
   "questionType": "datefield",
   "questionLabel": "Date",
   "answers": [
        {
          "answerName": "date",
          "answerType": "datefield"
        }
    ]
  }, {
   "questionName": "dealer",
   "questionField": "dealer",
   "questionRequired": "1",
   "questionType": "textfield",
   "questionLabel": "Dealer",
   "answers": [
       {
         "answerName": "dealer",
         "answerType": "textfield",
         "answerDescription": "Description Text"
       }
   ]
  }
 ]
}

angular.module("app", [])
 .controller("MainController", MainController);

function MainController() {
 var vm = this;

    vm.save = save;
    vm.questions = json.questions;
    vm.translatedQuestions = [];
  
    function save() {
     var questionsClone = [];
     angular.copy(vm.questions, questionsClone);

     questionsClone.forEach(function (question, index) {
      angular.extend(question, vm.translatedQuestions[index]);
     });

     console.log(questionsClone);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <form ng-submit="main.save()" novalidate>
    
    <div ng-repeat="question in main.questions">
     <p><b>Name: </b>{{question.questionName}}</p>
     <input type="text" ng-model="main.translatedQuestions[$index].questionName" placeholder="Translate" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="center-block" >
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be assertive since you did not provide enough details, such as controllers, functions, etc, but I'll give you a path to create your json object.

1. In your form element you have set 'ng-click=submit()', instead, I would have a 'ng-submit=ctrl.generateObject'.
2. Inside your controller, add an empty object so your answers will be added inside of this, something like: '$scope.answers ={};' or 'this.answers={};'.
3. Make a function inside your controller, the one I mention in the 1st item:

   ```
   this.generateObject = function(answers){
     this.YourObjectToInsert.push(this.answers);
   }
   ```

Once again, it's very hard to understand your scenario, try to follow this line and maybe make your own function.

If you're using chrome, download **Angular Batarang Extension**, and use your **Browser Dev Tools** to navigate to **AngularJS** tab, so you'll see all your models, apps and controllers in there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited question, hope now it's more clear. But my main problem is that I can't get value of, for instance, `questionField` inside of ng-model. I need to set `ng-model` to `dateOfInspection`, and do it for all fields